# How do you select a join table from a many to one relationship in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this relationship:

```
Appointment belongs to task
Task has many appointments
```

I have an attribute in `task` called `is_pay_per_hour` which is a `boolean`.

My problem is I want to be able to to select all `appointments` where the `task` it belongs to is `pay_per_hour_type`.

I am using the following syntax but it is not working:

```
User.first.appointments.joins(:task).where(is_pay_per_hour: true)
Appointment.joins(:task).where(is_pay_per_hour: true)
```

Help please,

Comment: You were almost there: use `where(tasks: { is_pay_per_hour: true })` instead

Comment: Got it working. Thakn you! @MrYoshiji

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify this with the `where` method. For example

```
Appointment.joins(:task).where(tasks: {is_pay_per_hour:true}).all
```

Please [look here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for more information.

Comment: if the table's name is `tasks` then the where clause should be `where(tasks: { is_pay_per_hour: true })`